# How to pass Headers and request body in POST request?

Tags: java, spring, post, resttemplate

I am using  RestTemplate `restTemplate.exchange`method to POST request to an endpoint. I have `OAuth Header` and `HttpEntity` in different file which I want to pass to POST request, in addition to this I also want to pass `request` to the endpoint.

I was able to successfully pass the headers and request, but not Http entity which contains credentials

```
 ResponseEntity<String> result = restTemplate.exchange(uri, HttpMethod.POST,
                new HttpEntity<>(request, dataRepo.getHeader()), String.class);
```

Is there any way I can pass all 3 things

1. HttpEntity
2. HttpHeaders
3. request

Here is my code

```
@RunWith(MockitoJUnitRunner.class)
@TestPropertySource
public class DataTest {
    @Inject
    private Oauth oauth;

    @Mock
    private DataRepo dataRepo;
    RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplate();

    @Qualifier(OAuth2HttpHeadersBuilder.BEAN_NAME)
    NewHttpHeader headersBuilder;

    @Test
    public void testAddEmployeeSuccess() throws URISyntaxException {

        URI uri = new URI(url);
        Set<String> mockData = Stream.of("A","B").collect(Collectors.toSet());
        String onsString = String.join(",", mockData);

        Map<String, String> requestBody = new HashMap<>();
        requestBody.put("name", onsString);
        JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(requestBody);

        HttpEntity<String> request = new HttpEntity<>(jsonObject.toString(), null);

        ResponseEntity<String> result = restTemplate.exchange(uri, HttpMethod.POST,
                new HttpEntity<>(request, dataRepo.getHeader()), String.class);

        Assert.assertEquals(201, result.getStatusCodeValue());
    }
```

The below code is in NewHttpHeader.java file which contains 
`Header` and `HttpEntity`

```
     private HttpEntity<MultiValueMap<String,String>> getHttpEntity() {
            MultiValueMap<String, String> store = new LinkedMultiValueMap<>();
            store.add( "pas", "password" );
            store.add( "name", config.getVaultServiceAccountName() );
            return new HttpEntity<>( store, getHeader() );
        }


        private HttpHeaders getHeader() {
            HttpHeaders httpHeaders = headersBuilder.build();

            httpHeaders.add( HttpHeaders.ACCEPT, ContentType.APPLICATION_JSON.getMimeType() );
            httpHeaders.add( HttpHeaders.CONTENT_TYPE, ContentType.APPLICATION_FORM_URLENCODED.getMimeType() );

            return httpHeaders;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Why show us `NewHttpHeader.java`? It's not used by the `testAddEmployeeSuccess()` method.

Comment: This is test file for DataRepo where NewHttpHeader methods are injected, so that I can access them in test file

Answer (score 0):

Quoting question:

> Is there any way I can pass all 3 things
>
> 1. HttpEntity
> 2. HttpHeaders
> 3. request

Quoting javadoc of [`HttpEntity`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/http/HttpEntity.html):

> Represents an HTTP **request** or response entity, consisting of **headers** and **body**.

So the answer to your question is: **Yes**, you can pass all 3, since the first is nothing but a combination of the other two.

Just merge your two `HttpEntity` objects.

*Before*

```
HttpEntity<String> request = new HttpEntity<>(jsonObject.toString(), null);

ResponseEntity<String> result = restTemplate.exchange(uri, HttpMethod.POST,
        new HttpEntity<>(request, dataRepo.getHeader()), String.class);
```

*After*

```
HttpEntity<String> request = new HttpEntity<>(jsonObject.toString(), dataRepo.getHeader());

ResponseEntity<String> result = restTemplate.exchange(uri, HttpMethod.POST,
        request, String.class);
```

Comment: I tried but it is not working, I am still getting 401 unauthorized at post request. Also if I call getHttpEntity, then I do not need to make call to get httpHeaders, so is there any way I can replace gethttpheaders with gethttpentity ?Thank you

Comment: It's probably because your headers are wrong. Since we don't know what headers you're sending, and we don't know what the server needs to authenticate you, we can't really help with that.

Comment: Okay I can look into that, but by merging HttpEntity do you mean the credentials present in `getHttpEntity()` and `requestBody` (which is JSON data) must be combined as single HttpEntity? If yes then is that a good approach?

Comment: The first parameter of the `HttpEntity` constructor specifies the **body** of the `POST` request. A request can only have one body, so having a `POST` request with an actual payload (`jsonObject`), that is also supposed to have user/password in the *same* request body, that makes no sense, at all. Authentication either requires a *separate* request to "log in" to the server, and then carry some value forward to the next request, e.g. a cookie, *or* it requires authentication values to be in the headers. Take a step back and re-evaluate from scratch what you're supposed to be doing here.

Comment: This the above code is unit test, while making POST with exchange it is throwing 401 unauthorized error. So I thought headers might be problem. I am using http://localhost:3000/project/messager which is the actual endpoint where I am making post request. Is there anyway I could just make mock post to endpoint or use mock endpoint. So that my test is success and status code of 401 is no longer a problem. If yes could you provide some suggestions on how to proceed? Thank you